# How to add effects on bitmap in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an android Application that will add effect on Bitmap.
Is there any library for generating effects on bitmap?

Please provide me a sample or a link .I search on google and also on stackOverflow but i
couldn't find any thing helpfull.

thankx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you need to create your own filter / effect code. There's no library at the moment.

I've created application like instagram that have several filters. To do this, I have to manually build the filter by reading online photoshop tutorials as well as academic papers related to it.

Here's some resources that might be useful for you:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection
- [Fundamentals of Image Processing](http://www.tnw.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Faculteit/TNW/Over_de_faculteit/Afdelingen/Imaging_Science_and_Technology/Research/Research_Groups/Quantitative_Imaging/Publications/List_Publications/doc/FIP2.2.pdf)
- [Image Processing: The Fundamentals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047074586X)